# alternative source for installing git. brew install git; kernel.org Down for maintenance

Tags: git, homebrew

i just noticed that kernel.org is Down for maintenance. is there a different formula which uses a different mirror ? or could i add a different source (like bundler?) to homebrew?

thx for help!

Comment: It's down because kernel.org was hacked:  http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/08/31/linux_kernel_security_breach/

Comment: I just merged mirror support into Homebrew---`brew install git` should now automatically route around kernel.org until it comes back online.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Quick workaround:
Perform 
`brew edit git`

**And put**

`url 'https://github.com/git/git/tarball/v1.7.6.1'`

`md5 'ab731cf9b99529f3f8d126aa15d9a1cd'`

**Instead of**

`url 'http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'`

`md5 'd1e00772cc9dc6c571999feb9e8771ab'`

**Also put**

`url 'http://ftp.uk.freesbie.org/sites/ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/git-manpages-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2`

**instead of**

`url 'http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-manpages-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'`

**And also put**

`url 'http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/ftp/pub2/software/scm/git/git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'`

instead of

`url 'http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'`

Save and after that type `brew install git`.

When Linus is done with kernelorg's maintenance, you can revert all these changes.

**UPDATE:**
Added mirror for htmldocs as well. Credits to Tadashi Shigeoka who found the url.

**UPDATE:**
Recent homebrew revision contains mirrors, so that you don't need to use this hack.

Comment: awesome. how did you figured out the md5 part?

Comment: That's different archive (tar.gz instead of tar.bz2), so different md5

Comment: Another mirror for git-manpages: http://212.219.56.139/sites/www.ibiblio.org/gentoo/distfiles/git-manpages-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2

Comment: So I ran these commands, and when I run `git version` it says version 1.7.4.4. that is the version that is installed outside of homebrew. The real kicker is that when I run `which git` it points to the git binary installed by homebrew. I'm lost at this point and have no idea which version I'm actually running.

Comment: For anyone else arriving here, this solution was great as an interim but now Sharpie has updated the mirrors @Day Davis Waterbury's answer is the simplest and the best.

Answer (score 9):

**Updated for 2015:** The solution is **much** simpler asssuming you have ruby.

@Sharpie added mirror support several years ago. The top answer here is more work than necessary. Do this instead:

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

And then:

> brew install git

Comment: When I originally posted this answer, the homebrew install script was at https://raw.github.com/gist/323731, but the text there now says that the script has been moved to https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb. However, since that doesn't link directly to the raw script (it's the regular github view), I updated the link with the raw view instead.

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble resolving the link to the git-manpages.  The manpages are also available at the above git-htmldocs url.

```
url 'http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/ftp/pub2/software/scm/git/git-manpages-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the mirror site to download 'git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'

url: http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/ftp/pub2/software/scm/git/

**put**

> url
>   'http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/ftp/pub2/software/scm/git/git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'

**instead of**

> url
>   'http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'

Answer (score 2):

I found out that freesbie.net was down when trying to install the manpages but you can use

```
url 'http://distfiles.macports.org/git-core/git-manpages-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'
```

instead of

```
url 'http://ftp.uk.freesbie.org/sites/ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/git-manpages-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Had an issue with `git-htmldocs` url, kept getting connection reset by peer.

Noticed that the files were downloaded and kept in `/Users/vish/Library/Caches/Homebrew`

So just downloaded `git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2` from [here](http://git.exherbo.org/summer/packages/dev-scm/git/index.html)
and moved it into the directory.

Answer (score 0):

the HTML docs are available here:

```
  http://mirror.linux.org.au/software/scm/git/
```

Answer (score -1):

Git source is also mirrored on github (I forget where off the top of my head, but a quick search will find it)

Comment: The question was not about source code, but about installing Git via homebrew.

Comment: No - the question said " or could i add a different source (like bundler?) to homebrew?" my answer- yes, the source is also mirrored on github.