# Unable to install Git using Homebrew

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion, homebrew

I have been trying to install Git using Homebrew on OSX Lion for over a week now, with no luck. Other installs have been fine, what am I doing wrong please?

```
MacBookPro:Rails pingu$ brew install git
==> Downloading http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew\ 0.8\ (Ruby\ 1.8.7-249;\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.7) http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2 -o /Users/pingu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2
```

Comment: You are getting an `HTTP 503` error in `curl`. If you try to go to http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/, you'll see why, the site is down for maintenance. I'm not sure if it's been down for a whole week or not, but I'd try after you don't see that message anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [alternative source for installing git. brew install git; kernel.org Down for maintenance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360214/alternative-source-for-installing-git-brew-install-git-kernel-org-down-for-main)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you follow the link that 'brew install git' spits out - you will find that the website is "Down for maintenance". That's why it is not working!

A clever SO'er found the solution to this problem by using a mirror for the tar. [You can read his instructions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360214/alternative-source-for-installing-git-brew-install-git-kernel-org-down-for-main/7370964#7370964)

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the [URL](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2) yourself you will notice the huge Maintenance warning. This is probably connected with the recent [security breach](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Security-breach-at-kernel-org-1334642.html) on kernel.org.

Just try again later when the kernel.org admins are sure that the systems are save.

Answer (score -1):

It is worth keeping a chart of the major status codes, handy. A good source is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

404's are well known enough, but the 500 series, as indicated, reflect a server problem. Good web developers should also be looking at their logs, and if, for example, they are getting regular hits from a link to a location that they now no longer use, they should return a '301' (Moved Permanently), which may trigger the referring linker to update their link (or not).

Comment: Was this meant to be an answer for a different question? It doesn't directly address the problem the OP is having.