# Trying to use alternate links to install Git via Homebrew. Getting Error on htmldocs

Tags: git, homebrew

I am attempting to install git using Homebrew.  I used the answer located here: [alternative source for installing git. brew install git; kernel.org Down for maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360214/alternative-source-for-installing-git-brew-install-git-kernel-org-down-for-main/7370964#7370964) to try and get it installed as kernel.org is down.  However, I am receiving the following error on the htmldocs link:

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew\ 0.8\ (Ruby\ 1.8.7-174;\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.6.8) http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/ftp/pub2/software/scm/git/git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2 -o /Users/rickyrickard/Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-htmldocs-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2
```

Please advise on what I need to do to correct this error and have git installed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem is due to a disk error. See the readme: http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/ftp/README.TXT

Comment: That would certainly explain the error.  Is there an alternative to this to get htmldocs for git?

Comment: @RickRichard see duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360214/alternative-source-for-installing-git-brew-install-git-kernel-org-down-for-main There is an answer which says to download the file manually from a different site (linked there) and place it manually in the homebrew folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alternative source for installing git. brew install git; kernel.org Down for maintenance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360214/alternative-source-for-installing-git-brew-install-git-kernel-org-down-for-mai)